# Sorting result of views using data from another table

Tags: views

Sorry, pretty new to Drupal and Views so hope you guys can give me a few pointers.

I am trying to display a list of popular users on the front of my website. Noticed that pagewatchers has a table with the user id to visited urls like so (sid=>"9900",url=> "user/1234").
I have the basic idea of a query that would sort users against the count of urls matching 'user/$user->uid%'
though unsure how i would do this in views? Do i use the sort criteria and Global:PHP? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Pagewatchers shows the current users on any given page, but does not appear to track history (unless cache is disabled - but even then, it doesn't appear its set up to track ongoing data) - you want to show who is viewing the front page? or are you trying to show who most commonly logs in? or who most commonly views a given page?

Comment: I might be wrong, but looking in pagewatchers_sessions table, i see pretty old data in there like a week old.

Comment: Sorry, hit post by mistake. The table data seems to be like so : (url | sid | timestamp) , eg:- ("user/9817", "9000", "1434170472") and i see duplicate entries in url with just the sid changing to another user. So my idea was to do a count of user/xxx occurances when listing users in front page and sort them, so we know who the most popular user was (we are using profile2 module to let users have custom content in their profiles, why knowing if someone is popular would look nice) in the past week. Not sure if this is possible using views.

Comment: I think pagewatcher's tables should be considered unpredictable and unreliable since what you are looking for, is not what it is intended to provide. You may have to write a small custom module to do this

Comment: Yep, that's what i was afraid i would have to do eventually. Thanks for your help though :)